# Adding Android dependencies to Docker build image - Bitbucket Pipelines (CI)

Tags: android, docker, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I received this error during a bitbucket pipelines build. I am missing the firebase jar fles.

**Build fail error:**

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/usr/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/10.0.0/firebase-core-10.0.0.pom
         file:/usr/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/10.0.0/firebase-core-10.0.0.jar
         file:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/sdk-manager/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/10.0.0/firebase-core-10.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/usr/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-ads/10.0.0/firebase-ads-10.0.0.pom
         file:/usr/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-ads/10.0.0/firebase-ads-10.0.0.jar
         file:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/sdk-manager/com/google/firebase/firebase-ads/10.0.0/firebase-ads-10.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/usr/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/10.0.0/firebase-messaging-10.0.0.pom
         file:/usr/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/10.0.0/firebase-messaging-10.0.0.jar
         file:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/sdk-manager/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/10.0.0/firebase-messaging-10.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         project :app
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

**Details about the environment:**

- Android Studio project using Gradle
- Bitbucket (Cloud) Pipelines CI
- Using uberdevelopment docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/uber/android-build-environment/)

**What I want to accomplish:**

To install Firebase and other future dependencies for my build in my Docker container so Pipelines can build my Android project

**What I have so far:**

The application builds fine locally. You need to install Firebase on the machine that's doing the build (this is normal) in Android studio. However all the instructions for installing Firebase are for either the Javascript library or involve opening Android Studio and installing it, which isn't possible in a docker container.

**My current idea:**

Copy the compiled jar files in the build directories.

ie:

```
app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.firebase\firebase-core\10.0.0\jars\classes.jar
```

Rename it and copy it to the expected directory that the build expects

I'd rather wget it straight from a web resource and copy it that way because of two reasons:

1. I'm not sure if that's the jar file it wants
2. If it does work, it's cheating as I'm grabbing an artifact from an old build. Kind of defeats the purpose of a CI system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

If you're looking to import google play services and other android services (in app billing, and others) I made an image that covers this:

docker pull epro95z28/androidservices

It is based around the uber dev image found here: https://hub.docker.com/r/uber/android-build-environment/ )

This is the line I changed in the uber image to include the other libraries

```
ENV ANDROID_COMPONENTS platform-tools,android-23,android-24,build-tools-23.0.2,build-tools-24.0.0, extra-android-m2repository, extra-android-support, extra-google-admob_ads_sdk, extra-google-analytics_sdk_v2, extra-google-google_play_services_froyo, extra-google-google_play_services, extra-google-m2repository, extra-google-play_apk_expansion, extra-google-play_billing, extra-google-play_licensing, extra-google-webdriver
```